# How do I deal with Warrior stuns?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Warriors (hammer-using Warriors in particular) seem capable of greatly turning the tables in their favor when they land a Stun on me, typically resulting in me losing about half of my health or more throughout the duration of the Stun.

- What should I look out for to prevent being stunned?
- If I get stunned, how should I react to avoid their burst?

If it matters, I am an Elementalist, which means that my stun break (Armor of Earth) is also my primary source of Stability.

Comment: As Mr Miyagi said, "Best way to avoid punch - no be there." Dodge when you see the windup, use stability to avoid it or stun breakers to get out of being stunned. Pretty self-explanatory, look up "stun breaker" and "stability" on the wiki and you'll see a list of skills/traits/etc. that affect these for each class. Not sure what else you're looking for with this question...?

Comment: I honestly don't know what skills a Warrior uses to stun, nor what they look like. When I ask in Heart of the Mists, people always claim it's a really noticeable big swing, but it seems to come out of nowhere without warning. Maybe an animation of what to watch for would help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things you can do :

- [dodge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Dodge) when you see it coming
- [stability](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Stability) to prevent its effect
- [stun-breaker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Break_stun) when you didn't react in time or have no other options

The best way to find out how it looks like is to try it yourself, this way you will know exactly how it looks like. You can create a new character warrior and go to the PvP zone and try it out. If you don't want to go through that, go on youtube !

The main stuns of a warrior are :

- a big swing with hammer : [Backbreaker](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Backbreaker)
- a shoulder dash : [Bull's charge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bull%27s_Charge)
- a hit with a shield :  [Shield bash](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shield_Bash)

As an Elementalist you have a number of skills which can break stun :
(Credit to [DavidYell](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5357/davidyell) for adding the elementalist skills)

- [Arcane Shield](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Arcane_Shield)
- [Armor of Earth](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Armor_of_Earth)
- [Mist Form](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mist_Form)
- [Glyph of Elemental Power](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glyph_of_Elemental_Power)
- [Signet of Air](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Signet_of_Air)

P.S. : For PvP I really recommend trying out every class to better understand its mechanics, reading information and guides on it is great, but experience is key!

Comment: I was not aware that all of those Elementalist skills were stun breaks. This was very informative!

Comment: Seconding the "PS" - it's so vital to try out a few classes. I used to be confused by mesmers until I played one. I had no idea engineers had tool belts to just spamspamspam with. Invisible engineers, rangers, high-evade builds, they all become palpable.

Comment: @Koviko is there still something you want to be added for the answer to be accepted ? Are there questions left aside ?

Comment: No, I just hadn't gotten around to my answer clean-up, yet. I occasionally run through all of my questions and accept answers all at the same time.

Comment: Technically there's also [Skull Crack](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Skull_Crack), using the mace.

Answer (score 1):

Add in blocks, pulls, knock downs, knock backs, wards, condition cleanse and blinds as well, so thats a few  ways to deal with stuns:

A hammer warrior will chain generally all of the 5 attacks, so if you dodge say Earthshaker, you might get hit with a Hammer Shock so they can line up Staggering Blow or Backbreaker. A good Hambow warrior will try to do all their Hammer attacks within their fire fields to maximise Might generation and to keep you stacked with burning.

The trick is to not let them chain, even stability isn't going to do much, you need to blind them during their AoE leap EarthShaker so they miss their Staggering blow, block them, make them come to your area damage (symbols, wells...). You need to be doing quick burst to keep your Vigor up immediately after you have interrupted them some how - so you can dodge more - you need to avoid 4 solid control effects.

Chill works well as a soft CC works as well. Save your condition damage to when their berserk stance has finished - sure their is an icon to indicate!

If you can nullify their CC and damage chain, without blowing your CC too much, dodge, blocks, soft CC once they switch to Bow, then its time to CC and burst them - not in their fire fields please. And constant cleansing please.

The hardest thing is most Hambow warriors will be high in vitality and have good toughness. I find I need at to at least survival 2 weapon swaps to get them down a bit and let them blow their cool downs, before applying several sequenced burst to counter them. In sPvP thats enough time for support to arrive to make it more fun.